# Random background image every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, image, random, colors

I basically found this code and I tried to change it a bit. Instead of colors, I tried using images, but it didn't work out very well. I have checked other similar questions but it didn't quite give me the help I was looking for, anyway.

As you can see in the code, it randomly changes backgroundColor every 5000 milliseconds, I'm wondering how I can make it randomly change pictures (Background image) instead of colors?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setbackground()
{
window.setTimeout( "setbackground()", 5000); // 5000 milliseconds delay

var index = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);

var ColorValue = "FFFFFF"; // default color - white (index = 0)

if(index == 1)
ColorValue = "FFCCCC"; //peach
if(index == 2)
ColorValue = "CCAFFF"; //violet
if(index == 3)
ColorValue = "A6BEFF"; //lt blue
if(index == 4)
ColorValue = "99FFFF"; //cyan
if(index == 5)
ColorValue = "D5CCBB"; //tan
if(index == 6)
ColorValue = "99FF99"; //lt green
if(index == 7)
ColorValue = "FFFF99"; //lt yellow
if(index == 8)
ColorValue = "FFCC99"; //lt orange
if(index == 9)
ColorValue = "CCCCCC"; //lt grey

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#" + ColorValue;

}
</script>
<body onload="setbackground();">
```

Comment: How did you set the bg image? Show that code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

function setbackground()
{
window.setTimeout( "setbackground()", 5000); // 5000 milliseconds delay

var index = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);

var ImagePath = "image0.jpg"; // default image

if(index == 1)
ImagePath = "image1.jpg"; 
if(index == 2)
ImagePath = "image2.jpg";
if(index == 3)
ImagePath = "image3.jpg";
if(index == 4)
ImagePath = "image4.jpg";
if(index == 5)
ImagePath = "image5.jpg"; 
if(index == 6)
ImagePath = "image6.jpg"; 
if(index == 7)
ImagePath = "image7.jpg"; 
if(index == 8)
ImagePath = "image8.jpg"; 
if(index == 9)
ImagePath = "image9.jpg"; 

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage="url('"+ ImagePath+ "')"

}
</script>
<body onload="setbackground();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do it:

```
function setBackground(urls, targetId) {
    setInterval(function() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length));
        var target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        target.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + urls[index] + ")";

    }, 5000);
}
```

Where `urls` is an array of image urls, and `targetId` is the ID of the container you want to change the `background-image` property of.

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stygsnm3/) (with kittens)

--edit--

Keep in mind that while the new image is loading, the background (behind the background-image) is visible.  To illustrate this, I set the `background-color` to red.  As a new image begins to load, you will see a flash of red (which ironically fits the kitten theme).

--edit 2--

I reread your question, and it looks like you want to change the background image of the body.  The function above (and in JSFiddle) works against a target ID.  If you want to use it on the body, you can give your body an id and run the function with the bodies' id as a parameter.  Or you can use this:

```
function setBackground(urls) {
    setInterval(function() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length));
        var target = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        target.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + urls[index] + ")";

    }, 5000);
}
```